# Confusion: decltype vs std::function

Tags: c++, decltype, std-function

I am confused a little over the following notation. I want to create a queue, that holds function callbacks. I thought this could be done the following way:

```
    int fun(int);
    [...]
    std::queue<std::function<int(int)>> q0;
    std::queue<decltype(fun)> q1;
    std::queue<int (int)> q2;
```

Full code https://onlinegdb.com/rkvAdPpmU

Unfortunately, `decltype<fun>` and `int (int)` are not allowed. To be honest, I prefer the `std::function` way of doing. Now for the next part...

I recently came up with a thing called `packaged_task`. I tried to define the template the same way as I did with queue:

```
    int fib(int);
    [...]
    std::packaged_task<int (int)> f0(fib);
    std::packaged_task<decltype(fib)> f1(&fib);
    std::packaged_task<std::function<int(int)>> f2(&fib);
```

Full code https://www.onlinegdb.com/B17iYvaQL

Compilation yield a different result. Now `std::function` gave `error: variable ‘std::packaged_task<std::function<int(int)> > f2’ has initializer but incomplete type`. Other ways of initialization are ok.

My questions:

1) Is `int (int)` equivalent to `decltype(fib)`, where `int fib(int)`?

2) While I understand that `std::function` is actually a templated class, shouldn't it be used the same way in `queue` and `packaged_task`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot store functions, but you can store function pointers:

```
std::queue<decltype(&fun)> q1;
std::queue<int (*)(int)> q2;
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/S1HYhPp7L)

- `decltype(fun)` is `int (int)`
- `decltype(&fun)` is `int (*)(int)`

`std::packaged_task` as `std::function` expects signature,

so both `std::packaged_task<int(int)>` and `std::packaged_task<decltype(fib)>` are ok.

`std::function<int(int)>` is a type, not a signature, so `std::packaged_task<std::function<int(int)>>` is invalid (not defined in fact), so unusable.